# php open excel file in browser

Tags: php, com

how to open excel file in browser ,

i dont want some thing like force download dialog ,

i want to open excel in browser somthing like in gmail when u click the excel file in the inbox, it will show browser itself,

same like , how to do in php.

Comment: You mean when it opens in Google Docs? That's an entire Excel clone for the web.

Comment: Afaik, you need extensions/addons for every browser that is supposed to open Office documents (just like you need for Adobe Reader). I am not sure how available these are in anything but IE.

Comment: well there is an online mixrosoft office solution. but i don't know how to give documents to it and then show it to someone else because it requires a Live account. the thing in gmail is a full grown solution made by google.

Comment: Do you need to actually open the file in Excel itself, allowing the user to edit cells? Or do you simply need to display data from an Excel file in a (read-only) grid?

Comment: @Bharanikumar - In that case, why not look at a library such as PHPExcel that can read your Excel file and then write out a formatted, static HTML version of those worksheets

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net):

```
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$inputFileType = 'Excel5';
$inputFileName = 'MyExcelFile.xls';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

**EDIT**

If your Excel file is Excel 2007 (xlsx) or later rather than Excel 2003 (xls) or earlier

```
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
$inputFileName = 'MyExcelFile.xlsx';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Comment: am getting error  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'The filename test.xlsx is not recognised as an

Comment: @Bharanikumar - If your file is Excel 2007 (xlsx) OpenXML format, then you need to use the appropriate reader, not the Excel5 BIFF reader of my initial example... see edit.

Comment: For exact desig aspect like gmail, we should use any css or i should call any php classes (like excel grid )

Comment: @Bharanikumar - Write your own variant of the HTML Writer then, the existing code should provide the basis for what you want.