# open Excel document in browser using php

Tags: php, excel, ms-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php open excel file in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861397/php-open-excel-file-in-browser)

I uploaded a excel sheet to my server, now i want to open it in a browser NOT forced download.
Is there any php library available for doing so.

I want to show it as a excel sheet with rows and columns.

Comment: You can't open an Excel spreadsheet in a browser (without some kind of Office plugin, maybe. My memories of Internet Explorer are hazy. But that would happen automatically). Being client-side, it doesn't have anything to do with PHP. You could generate an HTML wrapper/replacement for it with a download link, though.

Comment: This might point you in the right direction: http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/

Comment: @minitech google docs can be opened in browser i need some thing like that in my project...any php library to read excel and display it in browser

Comment: @PrasanthBendra: Google Docs is an office suite for the web. It stands to reason that you can open its documents online. Excel is not the same thing. If you're talking about how Gmail can display Excel attachments - Google Docs converts them. It's a Google thing.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a great answer to this right here! [php open excel file in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861397/php-open-excel-file-in-browser)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This link explains how to fetch data from excel and display it in a browser.... My requirement is different i want to show it as excel sheet, NOT, ONLY the data (It should show rows columns and menus etc)