# How to open an excel file in a browser on anchor button click in php

Tags: php, html, excel, yii2

I am new to `PHP` development. I have an anchor button in my `PHP` view. Right now I am downloading the excel file on the anchor button click. But now I want to open it in a browser and then print it from there. For this I have searched many articles and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3862092/6854117) solution but it doesn't tell how to call it.

For now I am doing the following

```
<a href="/inventory-web/Files/Example.xlsx" open class="btn btn-info" target="_blank" >Download File</a>
```

Here `open` is use to open the excel file. When I click on the button it does open a new browser but it gives the error.

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: browsers cant read excel format.

Comment: So is there any way to do it ?

Comment: do what? make a browser do something it cant do?

Comment: No to open it ?

Comment: **browsers cant read excel format.**