# How do I force Excel files to open in the browser instead of downloading

Tags: php, excel

Is there any way to open a excel files in the browser instead of download.I have a excel file view button

```
<a href="/manage/public/uploads/docs/2019/10/2362188.xlsx" class="action" title="download docs"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

When i click it instead of view file in the browser it will download.Any help would be Greatly appreciated .

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861397/php-open-excel-file-in-browser

Answer (score 1):

Excel Online is a service, the file needs to be stored in OneDrive or SharePoint for this to work.